# want to pass variable to aftersave() method after save(false) in yii

Tags: php, mysql, yii, web-deployment

Actually,
as you see below code,
in model two functions are calling

**$this->sendMailtoTutor()**,**$this->sendMailtoLearner()**

i want to check a condition in model that if that condition will true then only these both function will call otherwise not. Is there any way to pass attributes or variable so that i can check condition in aftersave().
my code is as below

**in controller**

```
public function actionBooking()
{
    $booking_temp = new BookingTemp();
    $this->performAjaxValidation($booking_temp);

    if (Yii::app()->request->isPostRequest && Yii::app()->request->getPost('BookingTemp'))
    {
        $booking_temp->attributes = Yii::app()->request->getPost('BookingTemp');


        //echo '<pre>';print_r($booking_temp->attributes);exit;

        if ($booking_temp->validate())
        {
            $extra_price = 0;

            $post_data = Yii::app()->request->getPost('BookingTemp');
            $cam = Cam::model()->findByPk($post_data['temp_cam_id']);

            $data = array();
            $data = $post_data;
            $data['temp_book_user_id'] = Yii::app()->user->id;
            $data['temp_book_cam_price'] = $cam->cam_price;
            $data['temp_book_duration'] = $cam->cam_duration;

            if ($post_data['temp_book_session'] == 2) {
                $data['temp_book_cam_price'] = 2 * $cam->cam_price;
                $data['temp_book_duration'] = 2 * $cam->cam_duration;
            }

            if ($post_data['temp_book_is_extra'] == "Y") {
                $extra_price = $cam->camExtras->extra_price;
                $data['temp_book_extra_price'] = $extra_price;
            }

            $price_calculation = CamBooking::price_calculation(Yii::app()->user->country_id, $data['temp_book_cam_price'], $extra_price);

            $data['temp_book_processing_fees'] = $price_calculation['processing_fees'];
            $data['temp_book_service_tax'] = $price_calculation['service_tax'];
            $data['temp_book_total_price'] = $price_calculation['total_price'];

            $booking_temp->temp_value = serialize($data);
            $booking_temp->user_id = Yii::app()->user->id;
            $booking_temp->tutor_id = $cam->tutor_id;
            $booking_temp_variable = 'check_aftersave';
            $booking_temp->save(false, $booking_temp_variable);
            //$booking_temp->saveAttributes(array('tutor_id', 'user_id', 'temp_value'));

            $created_at = Yii::app()->localtime->fromUTC($booking_temp->created_at);
            $created_at_time = strtotime($created_at);
            $end_time = $created_at_time + (60 * 3); // 3 min greater from created
            $end_time_format = date("Y/m/d H:i:s", $end_time);

            echo json_encode(array(
                'status' => 'success',
                'temp_guid' => $booking_temp->temp_guid,
                'end_time_format' => $end_time_format,
                    ), JSON_UNESCAPED_SLASHES);
            Yii::app()->end();
        } else {
            $error = CActiveForm::validate($booking_temp);
            if ($error != '[]')
                echo $error;
            Yii::app()->end();
        }
    }
}
```

**in model**

```
protected function afterSave()
{
    if ($this->isNewRecord)
    {
        $this->sendMailtoTutor();
        $this->sendMailtoLearner();
        if ($this->is_message == 'Y' && !empty($this->book_message))
        {
            Message::insertMessage($this->book_message, $this->book_user_id, $this->cam->tutor_id, $this->cam_id);
        }
        $user_profile_link = CHtml::link($this->bookUser->fullname, array("/site/user/profile", "slug" => $this->bookUser->slug));
        $cam_link = CHtml::link($this->cam->cam_title, array("/site/cam/view", "slug" => $this->cam->slug));
        $message = "You have a new booking from {$user_profile_link} for your {$cam_link}";
        Notification::insertNotification($this->cam->tutor_id, $message, 'book', $this->book_id);
    }
    return parent::afterSave();
}
```

How can I perform this?

Comment: so what you want your question title says that you want to skip aftersave() but in description you are saying that you want to run aftersave()??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hi See if you want to do it in the `afterSave()` of  `BookingTemp` `Model`;. Then you can define a `variable` in that `model` like

like

```
class BookingTemp extends CActiveRecord
{
public $booking_temp_variable;
............
}
```

now assign this variable before saving your model in actionBooking();

as

```
$booking_temp->booking_temp_variable = 'check_aftersave';
$booking_temp->save(false);// no need to pass a varible
```

now in your aftersave function you can easily get it like

```
protected function afterSave()
{
    if ($this->isNewRecord)
    {

         $this->booking_temp_variable; // this has your value
    }
    return parent::afterSave();
}
```

Don't forget to keep it in `rules` as `safe`

```
public function rules(){
// your rules
array('booking_temp_variable','safe');

}
```

Comment: @RahulBhati if it woks then mark it as your answer :)

Comment: can I do this same declaration thing in CamBooking model and call this variable in CamBooking model.

Comment: yeah but then you have to assign it a value before saving CamBooking model.

Comment: these are called virtual attributes which we used in yii.

Comment: You can even define its value at the time of declaring like                                                     public $booking_temp_variable =  'some value' ;

Comment: we have to check one condition in aftersave() in cambooking model at the time of save() of bookingtemp model.

is it possible.....?

Comment: No if you are saving bookingtemp then its afterSave will be called not cambooking.

Comment: thanks for your answer.
it helped me to solve problem.

Answer (score 0):

What exacly you want to do?

At first you have to know, that when you are calling save() method and u pass there two args - `false` and, `$booking_temp_variable` . The first arg says that you do not run validation, the second one is (should be) array of attributes.

> http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CActiveRecord#save-detail